# Maintain the file content using chef-client

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is it possible to maintain the specific lines in file using chef recipe.

example: fileA.txt

```
foo
foofoofoo
This is important content
This is important content
fooo
foofoofoof
foooooofoofofofof
```

In above example I have a name **fileA.txt** with two important lines, which are very important to me. if someone change only those 2 lines in file. next run of chef-client revert it back to the same state.

but if someone change other lines which are not important me, it will not revert it back.

```
file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
   content 'foo
   foofoofoo
   This is important content
   This is important content
   fooo
   foofoofoo
   foooooofoofofofof'
   action :create
end
```

The above code revert back other lines also which i don't want..
Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't what Chef does. It manages the entire content of a file with the file resource. You will need to create your own custom resource if you want a file handling resource that does this. However, given how file manipulation like that would normally work this is going to be pretty specific to the file contents. You really need to encourage that everyone editing a file does so the same way. You shouldn't be partially managing a file with Chef and then letting others manage another part of it a different way. They should update the Chef code appropriately.

If you want people to manage parts individually you can look at [partial templates](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#partial-templates). However, this still requires they manage their portion in a way Chef can import and understand and they aren't manipulating directly on the server.

EDIT: See comments below, this is for the sudoers file and in that case the [`sudo`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_sudo.html) resource should be used.

Comment: Thanks for information,  actually I have file called /etc/sudoers in which I have some important sudoers entry which is required for my project. suppose if  I have maintained the entire files using my recipe and in future someone from sever or linux team added few more entry then my chef client will revert to backup to the old stage which i don't want so i want to manage specific entry which is require for my project

Comment: Okay but which property i can use for managing the entry inside the files.

Comment: There are examples at the bottom of the link https://docs.chef.io/resource_sudo.html#examples